# Autolayout Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I want to layout a label in the right corner of its `superView` with `8pt` trailing and `10pt` from bottom

This is my code :

```
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
  label.text = "text goes here"
  label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  label.numberOfLines = 0
  label.textAlignment = .Right
  label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  label.font = UIFont(name: "TheSans-Plain", size: 17)
  imageTitleContainer.addSubview(label)


    let label_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(>=8)-[label]-(8)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label":label])

    let label_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[label]-(10)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label":label])

    imageTitleContainer.addConstraints(label_constraint_H)
    imageTitleContainer.addConstraints(label_constraint_V)`
```

but I am getting `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` in `console`

`Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55acf24c0 H:[UILabel:0x7ff55acf1af0'text goes here']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff55acbf430 )>`

Note : `0x7ff55acbf430` is my `imageTitleContainer` in the code

**Update:** other constrains:
`"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55accdc80 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff55acbf430]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff55acca080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55accdcd0 H:[UIView:0x7ff55acbf430]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff55acca080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55acf2450 H:|-(>=8)-[UILabel:0x7ff55acf1af0'text goes here']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff55acbf430 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55acf24c0 H:[UILabel:0x7ff55acf1af0'text goes here']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff55acbf430 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff55adb3830 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7ff55acca080(0)]>"
)`

Comment: What other constraints are mentioned in the console? There should be a list of all constraint that should be applied.

Comment: @JörnBuitink I updated my question

Comment: its because of conflict in horizontal constraints one side you are applying `>=8` and another side fix constraint. Remove `>=8` Leading constraint just apply trailing constraint `-8-` and if require set appropriate width.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara then if the text is long the label width will bypass the superview width

Comment: @Bobj-C in that case either define specific width and set `linebreakmode` of your label. or apply leading constraint also `-8-` to fixed size.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara What if I want the label to expand vertically to show all its text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to lower priority for one of your constraints, e.g.

```
H:|-(>=8@999)-[label]-(8)-|
```

This has to be done to allow UICollectionView to do its layout work. Note zero-width constraint named `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` which breaks your layout.